# Does throwing an Exception have to cause the program to terminate

Tags: java, exception

Does throwing an Exception have to cause the program to terminate?

I think its no, I just want to make sure

Comment: In what language/environment?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the thread where the exception is thrown, and on the other threads running on the same time in the application.

An **uncaught** exception terminates the thread where it was thrown. If the rest of the threads are only daemon threads, then yes, the application will be terminated.

According to [Thread.setDaemon(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) documentation:

> The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.

Answer (score 3):

In Java and .NET, if you don't handle an exception, it will most like cause your program to terminate.

Simply throwing an exception will not terminate the program, as such. It is what happens after it was thrown that determines what will occur.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not have to cause it to terminate. You could catch the exception and do something useful with it, like show a message to the user that an error occurred and why.

Answer (score 2):

Failing to catch an exception will likely cause the program to terminate, but the act of throwing one will not.  At the very least, any application should have some kind of last line of defense for catching all otherwise unhandled exceptions and handling them (even if handling them means, for some at least, throwing them outside of the application and terminating because something external to the application expects this).

Answer (score 2):

Only "Unhandled Exceptions" will cause your program to crash. To handle exceptions you use the following form

```
try {
        // May Throw ApocalypseException
        functionThatMightBlowUpTheWorld();
    }
catch (ApocalypseException e){
         System.err.println("We accidentally almost blew up the world because: ");
         System.err.println(e.message);
}
```

Comment: Wait...is this code taken from WikiLeaks? I think this should never be released, **EVER**! lol

Comment: I enjoy coming up with funny examples. :) However, if you are having trouble with micro controllers on your centrifuges, I am not responsible.